# MS Access, passing the total of all outstanding loans to a query to find the percentage of loans outstanding to the total loans for each record

Tags: ms-access, ms-query, expressionbuilder

I am fairly new to MS Access so I'll share all pictures and share what I have come up with so far.

I have records of  sales agents with loans sold and outstanding loans balances. I want to be able to calculate the outstanding loan balance per agent over the total outstanding balances, taking into consideration the days the loan has been in arrears. I have managed to split the original source data using queries into two tables, Loans in arrears above 15 days and 13 days.

[Loan in Arrears Above 15 Days](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDakO.png)

I would like a simple efficient way to be able to get the total outstanding balances for all the agents then find the percentage each agent contributes to the total i.e.

= (individual loan balances 15 days in arrears)/total outstanding loan balances

Comment: Would require a subquery that aggregates outstanding balances. Otherwise, build a report. This is a common topic. Do research and when you have code with specific issue, post question.

Comment: A very simple example https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/query-to-get-percentage-of-records-in-table-access/153f4d91-1010-492e-b2cc-fdeb37bf2c3c. More info http://fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/query/index.html#Percent_of_Total

Comment: continuing from the comment by June7, show us some table(s), show us some sample data, show us the results you want.  What you want to do is not particularly hard or time consuming, but giving you an answer you will like is hard to do unless you refine your question.  see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example